# Use View from a Query across multiple SELECTS

Tags: sql, db2

I've got a query in similar structure to below

```
SELECT blah
FROM   A, B, C
WHERE  $SOME_COMMON_IF_AND
AND    $SPECIFIC_1

UNION

SELECT blah
FROM   A, B, C, D
WHERE  $SOME_COMMON_IF_AND
AND    $SPECIFIC_2

UNION

...
```

In am attempt to reduce query time, I'm trying to strip out the $SOME_COMMON_IF_AND parts and project it as a view, and have the SELECT clauses use this view as a baseline.

I can't seem to figure out the correct syntax to do this, any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

--- EDITED FOR MORE INFO---

For example:

```
(SELECT blah
FROM   A, B, C
WHERE  $SOME_COMMON_IF_AND)
AS WORK_TABLE_1

%$@#%$@# -- the missing link

SELECT blah
FROM   WORK_TABLE_1
WHERE  $SPECIFIC_1

UNION

SELECT blah
FROM   WORK_TABLE_1
WHERE  $SPECIFIC_2

UNION

....
```

This is on DB2 but I'm look for a general SQL solution, the original query is a beast (1000 line +), hence me abstracting the WHERE clause. Please let me know if more clarification is needed.

Comment: What database?  Abstracting the details doesn't give us anything to really work with either.

Comment: I don't understand this question...

Comment: it is still confusing as to what your overall goal is here. you wish to create views so that you don't have to type out lengthy queries over and over from what I gather. beyond that, I don't get what you are asking for.

Comment: Very first think that may reduce query time is to use **UNION ALL** if possible.  This is possible if the UNIONed queries are disjoint.  UNION will actually compute a distinct set of all records, UNION ALL will take the rows produced as the are.  UNION ALL is much faster as it simply appends the next queries rows.

Comment: Extracting common query code into a view is usually possible without performance/execution plan impact.  Views over views over views can often be properly optimized by the query planner.  Using a query explain or visualizer can show if this is actually happening as you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a common table expression.  It's just like having an in-line view:

```
with 
work_table_1 as (
   SELECT blah
   FROM   A, B, C
   WHERE  $SOME_COMMON_IF_AND
)
SELECT blah
FROM   WORK_TABLE_1
WHERE  $SPECIFIC_1

UNION

SELECT blah
FROM   WORK_TABLE_1
WHERE  $SPECIFIC_2
```